# Cannot change a.text() within ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have below code, I want to change the <a> text and unbind the event handler.

```
$("a[class='cash-payment']").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text('Thank you！');
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url: 'process.php',
        data: {inv: $("input[name='invoice']").val(), action: "update"}, 
    })
    .complete(function(data) {
       // do stuff if ajax complete
    });
});
```

If I move the

```
$(this).text('Thank you！');
$(this).unbind('click');
```

into the .complete() function like

```
.complete(function(data) {
    $(this).text('Thank you！');
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

I got error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of
>   undefined

Comment: change .complete to done and check it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` this one must change. the `this` is the `data`, not the target link. just add `var link = $(this);` below or after `e.preventDefault();` then..

```
.complete(function(data) {
    link.text('Thank you！');
    link.unbind('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from

```
$("a[class='cash-payment']").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url: 'process.php',
        data: {inv: $("input[name='invoice']").val(), action: "update"}, 
    })
    .complete(function(data) {
        $(this).text('Thank you！');
        $(this).unbind('click');
    });
```

to

```
$("a[class='cash-payment']").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url: 'process.php',
        data: {inv: $("input[name='invoice']").val(), action: "update"}, 
    })
    .complete(function(data) {
        $("a[class='cash-payment']").text('Thank you！');
        $("a[class='cash-payment']").unbind('click');
    });
});
```

or you might want to put it in a variable

```
var variable = $("a[class='cash-payment']");
```

and change

```
$(this).text('Thank you！');
$(this).unbind('click');
```

to

```
$(variable).text('Thank you！');
$(variable).unbind('click');
```